# Do I change app.listen('port number') when I finally publish my website to a hostserver?

Tags: node.js, express, backend, namecheap

This is my first time publishing a website so excuse me if my question sounds dumb or easy. So I finally finished the frontend and backend of my website and I'm going to publish it to a hostname from namecheap.com. I'm using express and an abstract example of how my backend looks would be like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static("./public"));

app.listen(5000, () => {
    "server is listening!!"
})
```

I realize that using app.listen(5000, () => {}) is due to listening to a port in the local host. So how do I change it to finally publish it and for my hostserver to recognize it.

Comment: It depends on the hosting platform. They may want you to bind to the normal http/s ports 80/443 or they may not care and you just specify the port in the domain record.

Comment: It's a de-facto convention to use `process.env.PORT` if set.

Answer (score 3):

use `nginx` or `apache` upstream ,
apache and nginx as ssl termination , more secure and if you add caching you could handle more request per second
nginx config :

```
server {

#listen 80 ;
#listen [::]:80 ;

listen 443 ssl ;

server_name  namecheap.com;

ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/domain-crt.txt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain-key.txt;

ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m; # holds approx 4000 sessions
ssl_session_timeout 1h; # 1 hour during which sessions can be re-used.
ssl_session_tickets off;
ssl_protocols  TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_buffer_size 4k;


location / {

proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
proxy_buffering on;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you are gonna host the website you might wanna add a port variable and assign the following value to it.

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
```

When you are on localhost testing the website the port variable will use the

> 5000

value otherwise when hosting the hosting service provides its own port to run the server which is the

> process.env.PORT

make sure  "PORT" is all caps. Then for running the server-

```
app.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => {
   console.log(`Server Started at Port ${PORT}`)
});
```

That should do it!